# Why my iOS app don´t appear on notifications settings?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have a problem with my app. I have a distribution certificate with Push Notifications, I tested the .ipa and it's alright.

But, when I delivered the app to App Store, and the app was accepted and published, after download, my app doesn't appear on Notification Center in Settings.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: APN production certificate must be enabled in the settings in apple developer

Comment: I have the production certificate, and I tested it as ipa obtained by iOS Distribution Certificate. The notifications works well, but the app don't appear on Settings.